Next.JS cant build filters with my project
i am currently building a dashboard using nextjs language. this code is also connected to a test server database (currently local. i took a copy of the test server).
i need a filter for the orders that are in the database
i am trying to deploy a filter that would allow me to choose the time period and type of order. ive tried for weeks now to get it to work, but it just wouldnt. ill share what i currently have, hoping someone could offer me the help i need
enter image description here
[enter image description here](https://i.sstatic.net/pBTzPiQf.png)

Hi Alwaleed! Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.
